# Como triggar uma função Serverless a partir do CloudMQTT?

Tags: node.js, expressões-lambda, amazon-aws, mqtt

Estou tentando fazer a integração entre o Broker CloudMQTT com uma função AWS Node.js serverless porém não encontro nenhuma documentação de como fazer.

O objetivo é quando chegar uma mensagem no broker ele trigar uma função Lambda.

O que eu gostaria de evitar no momento seria usar o AWS IoT que oferece essa integração, pq eu ja tenho tudo implementado pro outro broker.

Valeus!

Comment: [veja se ajuda](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-js)

Comment: Olá @Jhessica-Kanda , A chamada de uma função lambda pode ser através de http ou utilizando API da AWS. Você pode expor uma lambda utilizando API Gateway, por favor olhe o seguinte link:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-call-api.html
Dependendo de onde seu Broker está localizado (na mesma/outra VPC, externo na internet, usando VPN ou Direct Connect) você terá que assegurar que ele pode acessar a função lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Basta criar uma regra que vincule o tópico à função, como documentado em https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pt_br/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-lambda-rule.html

Se quiser um exemplo de como fazê-lo pela linha de comando ao invés do console tenho um tutorial em https://internetof.healthcare, mais especificamente este notebook: https://github.com/InternetOfHealthcare/ehealth-workshop/blob/master/aws-iot-react-events.ipynb